# How to get starting creating a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I would like to start writing a WordPress plugin that will allow the user to play a scratch the card game (like the lottery). I would like to ask what programming language I should learn and how to get started. Is anyone with similar experiences and what are the recommendations you can offer ? Thanks in advance for your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Wordpress, you would need to know basic PHP, and also how wordpress works.
For this, I suggest reading [Writing a plugin for Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

For the scratch card, you can make this in CSS and JS. For an example, I refer you to [Canvas - Scratch Card](https://codepen.io/jmzelaya/pen/jKpYMo)

```
´
```

Comment: For another scratch effect, check https://codepen.io/milkmidi/pen/ajaxzw

Answer (score 0):

Like they said before, wordpress is using php. So you must learn php and how wordpress is functioning in order to be able to add stuff on your website.
You can look at simple existing plugin to help you. getting started